# Make another program think I'm holding down the spacebar for a second

Tags: c#, input, sendmessage, postmessage, sendinput

I'm trying to write a program that brings another program to the front and hold down the spacebar for a second.

I've researched all sorts of SendMessage, PostMessage, SentInput, etc ... and none of them seem to work, or else I'm just doing it wrong.

Anyone have a sure-fire method of sending keyboard input? Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - using the sendwait command?

Comment: I'll try that out when I get back home. That looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the SendKeys class - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If that doesn't do what you need then you could also try this: [how to perform a hold ALT+TAB sendkey event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951355/how-to-perform-a-hold-alttab-sendkey-event-in-c-sharp) which gives advice on how to hold a key down.

Comment: @Jonathan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.